# Using Appkit Framework in Launch Daemon

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, launchd, nsworkspace

I want to use NSWorkspace to check if [application is launched or closed](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2050/_index.html).

But the process is Launch Daemon and Apple documentation says its not thread safe.

However, the part of code that makes use of Workspace will not be executed at start up or login time. It will be executed after some commands received from other application via BSD communication and process is background process without UI?

Is it safe to use Appkit framework in this situation? Only NSWorkspace API and no other? Alternate solution is Polling? What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can use any code that isn't thread safe, as long as you are only doing one operation of whatever the unthreadafe operation is at any given time. I would go ahead and try it, and just be aware that whatever you are doing you can't do concurrently, if you absolutely need to do something concurrently you can try throwing a couple of @synchronized blocks around the code, either in callbacks of a long running background process, or delegate calls.